# bash help escape quotes on multiple subshells and eval

Tags: linux, bash, shell, paste

I have a script that needs to print contents of a file from multiple hosts side-by-side. I think the best way is to use `paste` and bash [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)

It works well in a single bash liner:

```
paste <(/usr/bin/ssh module-1 'printf %-30s\\n "module-1" && find /proc/icp_dh895xcc_dev*/qat -print -exec awk -F'"'[][ ]' '"'/AE/{if ($5%2==0) printf "%-9s AE %-2d: %-7d\n",$3,$5,$(NF-1)}'"' {} \;") \
<(/usr/bin/ssh module-2 'printf %-30s\\n "module-2" && find /proc/icp_dh895xcc_dev*/qat -print -exec awk -F'"'[][ ]' '"'/AE/{if ($5%2==0) printf "%-9s AE %-2d: %-7d\n",$3,$5,$(NF-1)}'"' {} \;") \
<(/usr/bin/ssh module-3 'printf %-30s\\n "module-3" && find /proc/icp_dh895xcc_dev*/qat -print -exec awk -F'"'[][ ]' '"'/AE/{if ($5%2==0) printf "%-9s AE %-2d: %-7d\n",$3,$5,$(NF-1)}'"' {} \;") \
<(/usr/bin/ssh module-4 'printf %-30s\\n "module-4" && find /proc/icp_dh895xcc_dev*/qat -print -exec awk -F'"'[][ ]' '"'/AE/{if ($5%2==0) printf "%-9s AE %-2d: %-7d\n",$3,$5,$(NF-1)}'"' {} \;")
```

When I try to create a script from it by building a command-line for each host, and running it via `eval` the escaping of the quotes and backslashes breaks.

This is the simple script logic I use:

```
#!/bin/bash

CMD="paste "
MODULES=( $(awk '/module/ {print $NF}' /etc/hosts) )
for ii in ${!MODULES[@]}
do
        CMD=''"${CMD}"' <(/usr/bin/ssh '"${MODULES[$ii]}"' ''printf "%-30s\\\\n" "'"${XIV_MODULES[${ii}]}"'" && find /proc/icp_dh895xcc_dev*/qat -print -exec awk -F'"'[][ ]' '"'/AE/{if ($5%2==0) printf "%-9s AE %-2d: %-7d\n",$3,$5,$(NF-1)}'"' {} \; '")"

done

echo '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ echo "${CMD}" ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
echo "${CMD}"
echo '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ eval "${CMD}" ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
eval "${CMD}"
echo '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
```

I've tried pretty much any combination to get it working for the past couple of days without luck. Please help :)

The files I'm trying to parse look like this:

```
# cat /proc/icp_dh895xcc_dev0/qat
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Statistics for Qat Instance 0                    |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Firmware Requests[AE 0]:                  637107 |
| Firmware Responses[AE 0]:                 637107 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Firmware Requests[AE 1]:                       0 |
| Firmware Responses[AE 1]:                      0 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Firmware Requests[AE 2]:                       0 |
| Firmware Responses[AE 2]:                      0 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Firmware Requests[AE 3]:                       0 |
| Firmware Responses[AE 3]:                      0 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Firmware Requests[AE 4]:                       0 |
| Firmware Responses[AE 4]:                      0 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Firmware Requests[AE 5]:                       0 |
| Firmware Responses[AE 5]:                      0 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Firmware Requests[AE 6]:                  675167 |
| Firmware Responses[AE 6]:                 675167 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Firmware Requests[AE 7]:                       0 |
| Firmware Responses[AE 7]:                      0 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Firmware Requests[AE 8]:                       0 |
| Firmware Responses[AE 8]:                      0 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Firmware Requests[AE 9]:                       0 |
| Firmware Responses[AE 9]:                      0 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Firmware Requests[AE 10]:                       0 |
| Firmware Responses[AE 10]:                      0 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| Firmware Requests[AE 11]:                       0 |
| Firmware Responses[AE 11]:                      0 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Mmmm [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: To reiterate fedorqui's point. Don't do that. Commands do not go in strings. It does not work.

Comment: I've tried switching to an array as the link suggests. Now can't get the process substitution to work. I'm still lost